# How to install F2FS mounting capability on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: kernel, filesystem, f2fs

The title basically says it all.

The reason is that I want to access a userdata partition dump of an Android phone from my WSL2 installation.

As understand this, I need to build an `f2fs.ko` file and then load it. But I cannot find a way to do that.

Comment: It is already installed and enabled by default.

Answer (score 1):

f2fs is a kernel module. It can be loaded into the kernel manually with

```
modprobe f2fs
```

For persistent module loading you need to add the name of the module to `/etc/modules`
e.g.

```
echo f2fs >> /etc/modules
```

This respone refers to ubuntu 22.04 and the current kernel  `5.15.0-56-generic`. The f2fs module can be found in `/usr/lib/modules/5.15.0-56-generic/kernel/fs/f2fs/f2fs.ko`

other - especially virtual - installations like WSL2 user other kernels which are not officially provided by ubuntu.

**Comments:**

- the question die not mention a virtualized installation. please provide as much info as possible.
- even if you use a virtualized installation please note that HW drivers of the host may be used. - especially at WIFI and filesystems.

Comment: modprobe: FATAL: Module f2fs not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.79.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2

Comment: correct, WSL does not use the default 22.04 kernel but a custom one.. see update in the response.

Comment: My original question did mention WSL installation. I also know that WSL images use custom-built kernels from Microsoft. I wanted to know if there is any way to build the f2fs.ko module and use it from WSL.